# SQL Linked Server query with Parameters

Tags: sql, linked-server

I need to select value from SQL Linked Server & get it to loacal variable

This is what I've written so far:

```
DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @FINALQUERY AS VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @OutVal AS VARCHAR(10)

SET @SQLQUERY = 'SELECT Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE Field2=' + CAST(@var1 AS VARCHAR) 
SET @FINALQUERY = 'SELECT @OutVal=Field1 FROM OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER,' + '''' + @SQLQUERY + '''' + ')'
EXEC(@finalQuery)
```

but this is wrong as it does not set the local variable(@OutVal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `exec`, use [sp_execute_sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) with an output parameter:

```
exec sp_executesql @FinalQuery, N'@OutVal output', @OutVal = @OutVal out
```

Since `sp_executesql` expects `nvarchar` parameters, be sure to change the definition of `@FinalQuery` to `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 1):

@OutVal in query string does not recognized as a variable. use a function or return table statement.