# Invalid column name '@clmn' and linked servers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

You do something like this

```
declare @v int
set @v = 1
INSERT INTO [LinkedServer].[mydb].[dbo].my_table(clm1, clm2)
SELECT  @v , val
FROM    [LinkedServer].[mydb].[dbo].other_table
```

and get

```
Invalid column name '@v'.
```

How to work around that?

Comment: This might help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314520

Comment: Which combination of SQL server versions have you tried?

Comment: @Alexander running command from sql server 2005 and linked server being 2014

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Linked Server query with Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202496/sql-linked-server-query-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do something like this:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = N'INSERT INTO [mydb].[dbo].my_table (clm1, clm2)
             SELECT @v , val
             FROM   [mydb].[dbo].other_table'
EXEC [LinkedServer].master..sp_executesql @cmd, N'@v int', @v
```